# Chaining and Callback Syntax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand the chaining and callback functions, but it seems I am missing something, since the code below does not work and stops before *slideDown*.

I would like to change the color of a paragraph to red when clicking on a button and then change the color to blue before initiating the *fadeOut*. Here is my code, based on a [W3Schools Tryit Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_chaining2);

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#p1").css("color", "red")
      .slideUp(2000)
      .slideDown(2000,css("color", "blue"))
      .fadeOut(2000);
  });
```

What is the proper way of doing the above?

Comment: you need to do the callback in the animation functions - eg `slideup(2000, function() { $(this).css("color", "blue") })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.css` method should be in a callback of `.slideDown`

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("#p1").css("color", "red")
    .slideUp(2000)
    .slideDown(2000, function () {
      $(this).css("color", "blue")
    })
    .fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: So this basically means that only defined functions can be fired as callbacks?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'defined functions'. However, you need to do it this way to ensure the effects happen in order. The `slideX()` methods operate on the `fx` queue, but `css()` doesn't, so you need to use the callbacks to ensure that the colour changes at the right time.

Comment: Also, @kmgt, I think the callback should go in the `slideUp`, so that the text is blue when the `slideDown` happens

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, this is exactly what I wanted, but your comment makes sense to be noted :)

Comment: I did not think so much about arrangement. Example is just to show the callback syntax.